# Slicing and jumbling an image using JS

Tags: javascript, image, css

I have an image and I want to cut it into 'n' horizontal pieces and then want to jumble them. Is there any possible way to do it using vanilla JavaScript / CSS without using any image processing library? I have the image url for the whole image.

Comment: have you tried canvas?

Comment: no. I was not aware that it can be done through canvas. will try it. Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, CSS's `clip` is the best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the way I can think of is to use the same way as css sprites

suppose you have the image, and create different css for 'n' pieces.

```
.pieces1 {
    left: 0px;
    width: 46px;
    background: url('img_navsprites.gif') 0 0;
}

.pieces2 {
    left: 63px;
    width: 43px;
    background: url('img_navsprites.gif') -47px 0;
}

.pieces3 {
    left: 129px;
    width: 43px;
    background: url('img_navsprites.gif') -91px 0;
}
```

then you can use

```
<div class="container"><div class="pieces2"></div><div class="piece3"></div></div>
```

to jumble them

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS's `clip` property.

```css
.container, img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#one, #two, #three, #four {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://s25.postimg.org/urlomcl1r/0_street_views_arden_street_2006_barry_nelson.jpg);
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 50px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, 50px);
}
#two {
  clip: rect(50px, 200px, 100px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, 100px);
}
#three {
  clip: rect(100px, 200px, 150px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, -100px);
}
#four {
  clip: rect(150px, 200px, 200px, 0px);
  transform: translate(0px, -50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
</div>

<img src="http://s25.postimg.org/urlomcl1r/0_street_views_arden_street_2006_barry_nelson.jpg" />
```

Comment: clip is now deprecated

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You can load the image in Canvas, cut it up and reassemble.

You use the Canvas drawImage method to cut up the image.

The drawImage() Canvas method is used for displaying image data directly onto the
canvas.

It takes the form;
    drawImage(Image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)

Where;

1. Image = Image that has been loaded on the canvas.
2. sx - Start position on the x axis of the rectangle you want to copy.
3. sy - Start position on the y axis of the rectangle you want to copy.
4. sw - The width of the rectangle starting at sx.
5. sh - Height of the rectangle starting at sy.
6. dx - X axis position where the cut triangle will be transferred to.
7. dy - X axis position where the cut triangle will be transferred to.
8. dw - Width of the cut image at the destination.
9. dh - Height of the cut image at the destination.

So drawImage( Image, 0, 0, 100, 200, 200, 200, 50, 100 ) means

Cut a rectangle of Image starting at position 0,0. The rectangle should be 100px wide and 200px high.
Place the cut rectangle 200px from the top and 200px to the right.
Reduce the size of the cut rectangle to 50px wide and 100px high.

See http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/JS/html5_canvas_draw_scale_slice.html